# How can I return an array of string from a function?

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I'm trying to get three string values from a query, but this call to the function:

```
argVals = GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName)
```

...fails to compile with the err msg, "*Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'.*"

Nor does this line at the end of that function compile:

```
Return args
```

...which fails with, "*Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'.*"

I am declaring argVals like so, as an array of string of three vals:

```
Dim argVals(2) As String
```

...and the function like so:

```
Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String
```

For more context, here is the pertinent code in its (I think) entirety:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connStr As String = "SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=vonnegut;PWD=ryecatcher"
    Dim upd8DML As String = "UPDATE CustomerCategoryLog SET Category = 'Exploding' WHERE Unit = @Unit And MemberNo = @MemberNo AND Custno = @CustNo"
    Dim coName As String
    Dim argVals(2) As String
    Dim _Unit As String
    Dim _MemberNo As String
    Dim _CustNo As String
    Dim curIndexVal As String

    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is CheckBox Then
            If DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                curIndexVal = CStr(DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox).Tag)
                coName = GetLabelTextForID(curIndexVal)
                argVals = GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName)
                _Unit = argVals(0)
                _MemberNo = argVals(1)
                _CustNo = argVals(2)
                Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr), _
                    cmd As New SqlCommand(upd8DML, conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _Unit
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _MemberNo
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _CustNo
                    conn.Open
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String
    Dim args(2) As String
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=salinger;PWD=dresdenoflions")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    cmd.CommandText = "select Unit, MemberNo, CustNo from Customers WHERE CompanyName = @CoName"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = coName
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
    sqlConnection1.Open()

    sqlConnection1.Open()

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
            args(0) = reader.Item(0).ToString()
            args(1) = reader.Item(1).ToString()
            args(2) = reader.Item(2).ToString()
    End If
    reader.Close()
    sqlConnection1.Close()

    Return args
End Function
```

What am I getting wrong here? How can I pass back an array of string from a function, and then store those vals in three vars (dims)?

NOTE: If I try to declare the function like so:

```
Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String(2)
```

...I get, "*Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring and initializing a string array in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262577/declaring-and-initializing-a-string-array-in-vb-net)

Comment: `GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String()` then `Return args`.  Pretty much the same as c# except using `()` as the array designator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you have the function signiture like so

```
Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String
```

When it should be like this

```
Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String()
```

The () at the end of the return type states that it will be a string array, and not just a string.